# Non-sudo alternative to /usr/local/bin for common scripts

Tags: command-line, bash, permissions, scripts

I'm used to putting common scripts in `/usr/local/bin` so that I can execute them from anywhere with the terminal.

For example, I make a shell script named `1`, make it executable with `chmod +x 1` and put it in `/usr/local/bin`, and inside the script I type `#!/bin/sh` on the first line, and then my commands. From there on, it's very conveniently usable and quick to execute by typing

`1`<kbd>`Enter`</kbd>

on the terminal, from inside any folder.

My problem is that I'm currently working on a computer where can't do `sudo` and I can't expect to get it either, so I can't place my script in `/usr/local/bin`.

What are my options? Is there another path with the same "run from anywhere" capability, which I can access without `sudo`, or another way to achieve something equivalent?

The accepted answer to [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/308045/differences-between-bin-sbin-usr-bin-usr-sbin-usr-local-bin-usr-local) says

> For user-scoped scripts, use bin/ in your home directory.

Which I tried, but there is no `bin` folder in my home directory, and when I created one, I still could not run the script from anywhere else.

I'm running on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Comment: Don't use 1 or something like that as script name. Try to calculate something in your shell: e.g. expr 1 + 1 (and if not you are doing it, some script will do it at some point for sure)

Comment: @frlan: How would `expr 1 + 1` be affected by the presence of a script named `1`?

Comment: True... not affecting `expr`, nor bash arithmetic `$(( 1 + 1 ))`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> What are my options? Is there another path with the same "run from
>   anywhere" capability, which I can access without sudo, or another way
>   to achieve something equivalent?

How to do it?

Create some dir in your home to hold your scripts normally named as `bin` as convention.

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Now move your scripts to bin

```
mv somescript ~/bin
```

Now how to make it tun from everywhere?!

You have to add the `bin` to the PATH

open your `.bashrc`

```
gedit .bashrc
```

and add this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/username/bin
```

*Don't forget to replace `username` with your User Name*

Save and exit, then source the bashrc

```
source .bashrc
```

and now you are fine, you can run your script as you used to do! but you have to notice this is related to your user only.

*Note: It's better to rename your scripts other than 1 ,2 since you may face some issues with that names*

---

UPDATE:

You can do same just create the bin dir in your home then `source ~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`. Since adding the ~/bin to your PATH is already listed in `.profile`

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

Comment: I use `export PATH=$PATH:$HOME/bin` so I can use the same bashrc for other accounts with different user names.

Comment: Just to mention `~/bin`  is in `$PATH` by default on Ubuntu. Just run `source ~/.profile` or log out/in after you created the directory.

Comment: @JacobVlijm In which version?!!! I use 12.04, 14.04, 15.04 and none of them has ~/bin in PATH

Comment: In *all* of them, I *always* use it, in many of my (accepted) answers as well, never got any comment on that, works her at home on five systems as well, but, as said, after running `source ~/.profile` . See (e.g.) here: http://askubuntu.com/a/247422/72216

Comment: @JacobVlijm some illusion here, I have 5 physical machines and more than10 VM and all of them has no ~/bin in PATH, I'm just making checks now and as I said. http://askubuntu.com/questions/402353/how-to-add-home-username-bin-to-path , http://askubuntu.com/questions/9848/what-are-path-and-bin-how-can-i-have-personal-scripts

Comment: I think you are the only one : ), I am pretty sure. Did you try creating it, add an executable, log out/in and run it?

Comment: Nope just run echo $PATH

Comment: I think what you say is related to `.profile` and you should source .profile not .bashrc, since in `.profile` you can find same as done above in `.bashrc`, so either do it manually as above or just create bin dir in home and source `.profile` and not `.bashrc`

Comment: @Maythux Ubuntu's default `~/.profile` [adds `~/bin` to the `$PATH`](http://askubuntu.com/a/49789/85695) if it exists. Since this is in `~/.profile`, you need to start a login shell or login graphically for it to take effect.

Comment: @terdon yes I know that, I was in argue with @jacob since he said it's already by default if just source `bashrc`, which is  the not the case since `.profile` add this not `.bashrc`. I already stated that, refer to the update and past comments

Comment: He said [source `~/.profile`, he never said source  `~/.bashrc`.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/643029/non-sudo-alternative-to-usr-local-bin-for-common-scripts/643030?noredirect=1#comment920827_643030)  :) Also, as a general rule, environmental variables [should go](http://superuser.com/a/183956/151431) in `.profile` and not `.bashrc` since they only need to be set up once. (none of this is to say that your answer is not good, mind you, and +1 from me)

Comment: Note that some distributions automatically add ~/bin to the PATH if it exists at login without you having to do anything else. Ubuntu does, for instance. Might be worth adding to your answer.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to https://askubuntu.com/a/643030/218015 you might can also define an alias inside your .bashrc for small, often used tasks. E.g.

```
alias ll='ls -l'
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
```

will create you a "command" ll, which is doing ls -l and ls will be coloured after defining the alias. https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/alias is having some more examples and a howto for setting it up.

Answer (score 3):

Try `~/.local/bin/`.

(I acknowledge this answer isn't adding anything new but there's a short answer to this question that shouldn't require reading everything else.)

Comment: Also see the answers [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36871/where-should-a-local-executable-be-placed) and [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316765/which-distributions-have-home-local-bin-in-path) for more reasons to use `~/.local/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

There really should be a per-user bin because it would be really helpful in multi user environments, where people are denied root privledges in order to make everyone more safe. Use the following in a bash script to automatically create it.

```
if [ ! -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
  mkdir -p "$HOME/.local/bin"
  printf '\nexport "PATH=$PATH:'"$HOME"/.local/bin'"' >> "$HOME/.bashrc"
  # Change the PATH right now:
  PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
fi
```