# bin doesn't exist

Tags: command-line, directory

I'm trying to make a symbolic link with node and nodejs, but it always returns :

```
No such file or directory
```

I've tried

```
$ cd ~/bin
```

just to get to the directory but it still says `No such file or directory`.
I don't think I have the bin file at all.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your `~/bin` related question, by default Ubuntu does not come with `~/bin` directory, if you want you can create it :

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Note that this is `$HOME/bin` i.e. if your username is `foobar` then `~/bin` or `$HOME/bin` expands to `/home/foobar/bin`. This directory is normally used for saving user specific binary files.

There is also a `/bin` directory, which is generally used for global binary files.

Answer (score 1):

> No such file or directory.]

Then you have to create it(normally not founded in Ubuntu), this is used for using non sudo  applications in local env. Check this :https://askubuntu.com/a/643030/150504.

now to create this dir easily run:

```
mkdir ~/bin
```

Now to make the binaries inside this bin available to global(To add this dir to PATH env variable), all you have is to source .profile:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to launch `nodejs` through `node` symlink, you need `nodejs-legacy` package.